# Tersely determining how many times a pair exists in a longer list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I am in the middle of writing a large piece of code and I want to shorten a length `or` expression.
Let's say we have a list, something like:

```
farm = ["cow","cow","cow", "hen","hen","hen", "fox","fox","fox", "hen","hen", "hen"]
lookup = ["cow","hen"]
```

I am supposed to check whether there are three consecutive elements of `lookfor` in `farm` list.

One way is to do:

```
for i in range (0,len(farm) - 2):
  if ((farm[i] == farm[i+1] == farm[i+2] == lookup[0])
     or (farm[i] == farm[i+1] == farm[i+2] == lookup[1])):
    # do something
```

Now if the number of elements in `lookup` is small, it can be written in the above way. However, if it is too long the code looks cumbersome and is harder to maintain. Is there a more concise way of writing the code, perhaps in list comprehension format - so that I do not have to manually write to look for all the elements of `lookup`?

Comment: Disagree with the close.  The OP already solved the "presence of a sliced list" problem - they're asking for a Pythonic way to check for the presence of any of an _arbitrary number of_ target sublists.  The linked question doesn't even mention that.

Comment: @TimPeters - I thought they were interested in reducing the `farm[i] == farm[i+1]...`. The additional original should solve the other challenge as well.

Comment: @motiur, you're looking for the `any()` builtin function, like `if any(<there's a slice matching the target * 3> for target in lookfor)`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, no, they explicitly said "Now if the number of elements in `lookfor` is small , it can written in the above way .However, if it is too long the code looks cumbersome ...".  Their question was entirely about what to do when `lookfor` "is too long".

Comment: @TimPeters - Yes, I was incorrect; sorry about that. Should be all fixed now.

Comment: Or maybe not fixed enough, I guess. Could've sworn I'd added all relevant originals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but something "like this" ;-) should work.  `any()` is a natural way to process an arbitrary number of `or`s, and `all()` for arbitrary number of `and`s.

```
if any(farm[i] == farm[i+1] == farm[i+2] == target for i in range(len(farm) - 2)
       for target in lookup):
    # do something
```

### If you need `i`

This variant will give you the matching `i` value, and is very much like your original code:

```
for i in range (0,len(farm) - 2):
   if any(farm[i] == farm[i+1] == farm[i+2] == target for target in lookup):
       print(i)
```

Comment: If I `print( farm[i], farm[i+1], farm[i+2])` I get `fox,fox,fox` - I was expecting `cow` and `hen` only.

Comment: Sorry, I can't guess what you mean.  In the code I gave, `i` is local to the comprehension, and would have no effect on any variable of the same name outside the comprehension.  If you _need_ the value of `i` where it matches, then that's a new requirement that wasn't mentioned in the original question.

Comment: See edit for an obvious way to capture the `i` value.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
gr = [(k,len(list(ns))) for k,ns in itertools.groupby(farm)]
for k in lookup:
    if (k,3) in gr:
        print k
```

will check for exact three consecutive keys.  For at least three, you can filter the groups by size and check whether each entry is in the lookup.